# Javascript ajax problem which makes the URL unreadable on the server side

Tags: javascript, ajax, esp8266

I need to send information from webside to server which i have already done with the following code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
//her definere vi varibaler
var Network = {"name":"", "password":""}
var json;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var Json = JSON.stringify(Network)

//her definere vi en funktion, som laver pop up boxes
function Info(sp) {
  let svar = prompt(sp, "skriv information her");
  return svar
}

//her kopiere vi data fra pop boksene over i javascript objekt
Network.name = Info("Indtast internet navn");
Network.password = Info("Indtast internet adgangskode");

//her logger vi objektet i consolen
console.log(Network);

//her sender vi netværks navnet og netværks adgangskoden til esp'en
 xhr.open("GET", "/network?Json="+Json+"}", true);
 xhr.send();
</script>
</html>
```

This code works, but here is a problem i dont know if it is a bug or a error that causes the problem. I receive the following error on my esp8266 from the ArduinoJson library when i deserialize the Json objekt the error is IncompleteInput. The problem is clear when I look at AJAX request [AJAX request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/achnC.png). It is easy to see that the text is missing the end } which is what i believe is causing the error. The reason why i believe that is that when i manually type in something it works like a charme. The question is how do I fix it.

Comment: _"/network?Json="+Json+"}"_: Why are you appending that final `}`? You object is already stringified.

Comment: You might have an issue here `xhr.open("GET", "/network?Json="+Json+"}", true);` there reason I say this is that you need to encode that JSON into base64. So, characters like espaces are turn into `%20`, check the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). Then, at the reserver, you need to uncode and convert the JSON string into a JSON object.

Comment: I did that because i saw that in the URL it was missing the } so i thought it might solve the problem, but it didnt.

Comment: I think the encodeing is fine because in the console it looks like this (XHR finished loading: GET "http://192.168.4.1/network?Json={%22name%22:%22%22,%22password%22:%22%22}}"

Comment: Generally you would pass JSON in the body of the request not in the parameters. Then you don’t need to worry about encoding issues. Previous comments are correct.

Comment: So what you are saying is that i should try to parse a string that can contain the entire URL and then just use the string instead of typing it manually into the URL part of xhr.open.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem was found in the HTML page that i showed in the post. User romkey told me to parse the string from outside the function where i open the XML object this worked immediately.This is the code that solved the problem,

```
<!--Her fortællers der, hvilket form for dokumnet det er-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
//her definere vi varibaler
var Network = {"name":"", "password":""}
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var Json;
var url;

//her definere vi en funktion, som laver pop up boxes
function Info(sp) {
  let svar = prompt(sp, "skriv information her");
  return svar
}

//her kopiere vi data fra pop boksene over i javascript objekt
Network.name = Info("Indtast internet navn");
Network.password = Info("Indtast internet adgangskode");

//her logger vi objektet i consolen
console.log(Network);

// her parser vi Netowrk objektet over i JSON (JavaScriptObjektNotation)
Json = JSON.stringify(Network)

url = "/network?Json="+Json

//her sender vi netværks navnet og netværks adgangskoden til esp'en
 xhr.open("GET", url, true);
 xhr.send();
</script>
</html>
```